# How can I import a Typescript 1.0 function like a node.js require with arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, arguments, typescript

I am converting legacy code to Typescript, and many other modules depend on the signature

```
var x = require("./someModule.js")(args);
```

In Node.js it is possible to do something like:

**moduleHello.js**

```
module.exports = function (message) {
    console.log("I'm a module and I say " + message);
}
```

**main.js**

```
require("./moduleHello.js")("Hello!");    // Should print "I'm a module and I say Hello!"
```

I've tried playing with the `export` keyword in Typescript, but it appears you cannot cleanly write it as follows:

**moduleHello.ts**

```
export function sayHello (message) {
    console.log("I'm a module and I say " + message);
}
```

**main.ts**

```
// Does not work, error TS1005: ';' expected.
import someVar = require("moduleHello")("I wish this worked");
// Also I'd probably have to call someVar.sayHello() instead, which I'm trying to avoid.
```

Can I write a single-line "require with arguments" in Typescript to maintain compatibility with my legacy modules? Or do I have to fall back to Javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `export =` syntax to assign a function to the export.

So:

**moduleHello.ts**

```
function sayHello (message) {
    console.log("I'm a module and I say " + message);
}
export = sayHello;
```

This will generate js of `module.exports = sayHello;`

Your main.ts code will now be able to require the function

```
import sayHello = require("moduleHello");

sayHello("This will work");
```

Comment: I was just looking at this, and it seems it only works if I don't export anything else... So now I have to figure out how to export other items along with the function. Maybe I can just spin those off into a different .ts file though. Thanks!

Comment: yeah if you do an export = function, then that will be the only function that can be exported within that module.

Comment: Right. I was able to solve this by splitting out various interface definitions to a separate *.d.ts file, and adding a Typescript reference to that file. Thanks again for your quick answer.